# Grammar in "I am the right person to discuss this with."

Tags: grammar

I understand

> I am the right person to discuss this.

because it equals

> I am the right person who can discuss this.

But I cannot understand the grammar in

> I am the right person to discuss this *with*.

It seems that it means

> I am the right person *with whom you can discuss* this.

but now "discuss" is not something "I" do, because it takes at least two people to discuss in this manner. Can I generalize this to a rule that when "person to do it" is used, it doesn't necessarily mean "the person" is the only one "to do it"? If not, why does it work here?

Comment: As with everything, it depends on context.  'I am the right person to discuss this with' is grammatical though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! I've edited your post to try to make your question clearer; if I've got it wrong, please feel free to make further edits (or roll back altogether and make your own edits). You can use the "edit" link right below your question on the left (between "share" and "close"). It would also help us give you better answers if you tell us what you've already looked up—for example, if you looked up the definition of "discuss", what did you find out? Finally, you might also be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the title phrase, "**I am the right person to discuss this with**," there is an implicit "you" in the meaning of the sentence. It is essentially "I am the person with whom you can discuss this." You are saying that you are the one with the knowledge or that you are the one who can follow through on whatever is being discussed. It is referring to someone else initiating a conversation with you about a topic.

Taking out the "with" at the end (as you do in the body of your question), though, changes the possible meaning of the entire sentence. If you say "**I am the right person to discuss this**," it is also saying that you are the most knowledgable person on that subject, but the subtle difference is that you mean that you should be with the one discussing it with others. So, if you were going to be speaking on a panel at a conference with 5 other people and you are the expert on topic X, you would say "I am the right person to discuss this," meaning your fellow speakers do not know as much about topic X as you do.